# Missing dependency in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have these recipes in my Makefile. They generate cross-compiled objects for ARM architecture and link them into an elf binary:

```
%.ao: %.c
    $(ARM_CC) $(ARM_CPPFLAGS) $(ARM_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

%.elf: %.ao startup_stm32f0xx.ao system_stm32f0xx.ao
    $(ARM_CC) $(ARM_FLAGS) $other_arguments -o $@ $^
```

This works fine from a clean build.
Contrary to my expectation, if I then say `touch foo.c; make foo.elf`, gmake responds with

```
make: 'foo.elf' is up to date.
```

If I try to `make foo.ao`, gmake says that it, too , is up to date.

What am I missing?

---

### Edit after reading the comments:

TLDR: I did have multiple rules matching the same target, as John Bollinger alluded and  HardcoreHenry said specifically.

In addition to the rules above, there's a rule for assembly sources so I can use those vendor files:

```
%.ao: %.s
    $(ARM_CC) $(ARM_CPPFLAGS) $(ARM_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

I had been debugging some macros, and used `-save-temps` to look at preprocessor output. This option also writes `.s` files. So after I'd run `make foo.elf`, I'd have the following in my directory:

```
foo.c
foo.i
foo.s
foo.ao
foo.elf
```

I can `touch foo.c`, but `make` sees that there's a `foo.s` which is older than `foo.ao`, and produces the output that it does. On a clean build, there is no `foo.s`, so `make` finds the `%.c:%.ao` rule and the build proceeds from `foo.c`.

(BTW, `.ao` stands for ARM object. In addition to cross-compiling for AMR, I compile many of the sources to run unit tests on the host, using the built-in `.o:.c` rule)

Comment: My only idea is that one or both of the files `startup_stm32f0xx.ao` or `system_stm32f0xx.ao` don't exist and can't be created (there's no rule in make that can build them).  In that case, this pattern rule won't match, and make will not fine any pattern rule that can build `foo.elf`.  If there's no rule to build `foo.elf` and it already exists, make will say it's up to date.

Comment: Or potentially foo.c disappears, or is modified after the foo.elf is built, which would cause the same scenario...  Double check the timestamps of the foo.c and foo.ao files.  That might give some clue.

Comment: `startup_stm32f0xx.s` and `system_stm32f0xx.c` exist, both come from the vendor (STM) and both assemble/compile fine (there's also a rule for `%.ao: %.s`). Make does remove `startup_stm32f0xx.ao` when it finishes linking `foo.elf`.

Comment: If `make foo.ao` fails, then the startup_stm32f0xx.a0 file will not matter.  Please check the date of foo.c and foo.ao after the failure (also, just checking -- is foo.c generated, and are you by chance on an Ext3 filesystem?)

Comment: Try running make with some trace/debug info. Start with `make foo.ao --debug`, this will print out the makefile's "decisions" on what to make and what not to with reasons like `File 'xzy' does not exist ... must remake target xyz` and so on. See if this shows you the reason why. But this won't show info on pre-requisits, for that you should increase the level further using: `make foo.ao --debug=v` (for verbose). Now you will get things like `Prerequsite 'abc.c' is older than target 'xzy' ... no need to remake 'abc.o'` and so on...

Comment: You say `startup_stm32f0xx.s` exists.  Do you have a recipe that will convert that into `startup_stm32f0xx.ao`?  Above you only show a rule that converts `.c` files into `.ao` files; you don't show a rule that converts `.s` files into `.ao` files.  I would invoke make with the `-d` option (redirect the output, it will be voluminous) and check what make says about trying to build `foo.elf`.

Comment: FYI, I don't think your problem has anything to do with failing to build `foo.ao` or `foo.c`.  If any of that were happening you'd get different messages than the one you mention above.  About the only way you can get the message `xxx is up to date` is if make doesn't detect anything wrong, but it can't find any recipe to run to update your target.  In the case of pattern rules, that can pretty much only mean that no pattern rule matched the target you want to build.

Comment: @MadScientist, don't neglect the possibility that `make` selects a rule (chain) for building the target with respect to which it really is up to date.  This is not necessarily the same rule (chain) that is chosen for it in a clean build.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't know if I really understood your comment, but it should definitely not be the case that make considers a different chain of rules to build a target that doesn't exist, from the chain it considers to build a target that does exist.  Certainly one or more of the recipes in that chain might not be run during each invocation of make: that's the point of using make... but the same set of prerequisites should always be considered.

Comment: @MadScientist, if `make` resorts to pattern rules for building a given target, then which one is selected is affected by which files exist or "ought to exist" when `make` runs.  It is possible, then, for a different rule to be selected when the build directory is clean than when it is not, and those may have different prerequisites.  The fact that the OP's build rules apparently remove some intermediate files makes such a rule flip more likely to occur.  A makefile that is susceptible to such behavior is no doubt of *poor form*, but not impossible.

Comment: Yet another possible scenerio -- if `foo.ao` is not being generated from the `%.ao:%c` rule in the first place -- Say `foo.s` exists and the `%.ao:%.s` pattern rule is defined before the `%.ao:%.c` pattern rule, then you would get the exact behavior as described...   Check your build log to see how `foo.ao` is built the first time.    Also, please check the timestamps!

Comment: @JohnBollinger, your scenario can only happen if there are multiple pattern rules that match the same target.  In that case, which one is chosen depends on the order in which they appear in the makefile and also on which prerequisites exist / can be built.  It would definitely be unusual for that to change from build to build, unless that is intended (as a shortcut for example).  I see no evidence in the question that this is the situation.  Also, you mention  "the OP's build rules apparently remove some intermediate files"; I didn't see that?

Comment: @HardcoreHenry I don't think you're correct that such a thing could lead to the described behavior.  The only way to get that output is if the pattern to build `foo.exe` doesn't match, and that doesn't depend on whether `foo.ao` is built from `foo.c` or `foo.s`.

Comment: @MadScientist - I tried it before posting:  `tmp> make foo.elf` `cp foo.s foo.ao`, `cp foo.ao foo.elf`, `rm foo.ao` (I used `cp` in my recipes.  The `rm` is done by make automatically to remove the intermediate file).   Then `tmp> touch foo.c; make foo.elf`, `make-3.81: 'foo.elf' is up to date.`

Comment: Do you have _both_ pattern rules `%.ao : %.c ; touch $@` and `%.ao : %.s ; touch $@` in your makefile, as well as a rule `%.elf : %.ao ; touch $@`?  If you do there's no way you can get the behavior you report.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry: you're right on the money. I did have a `foo.s` in my directory under some circumstances, and `make` was choosing that path. @John Bollinger: You are correct in identifying the multiple rule match as the source of my confusion. I edited my question with a longer explanation. If either of you want to write your comment up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of pattern rules.
*Make* can make very strange decisions on which rules apply depending on whatever is lying around on your hard disks.
It's all a bit arbitrary.

Much better IMHO to tell *make* exactly what files you need for a target.
It's pretty easy too.
Just prefix your pattern rule with the list of targets you actually want it to apply to.
This makes it a *Static Pattern Rule*.

```
objects := main.ao tools.ao devices.ao# etc

${objects}: %.ao: %.c
    $(ARM_CC) $(ARM_CPPFLAGS) $(ARM_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

%.elf: ${objects} startup_stm32f0xx.ao system_stm32f0xx.ao
    $(ARM_CC) $(ARM_FLAGS) $other_arguments -o $@ $^
```

As an added bonus, *make* now won't try to create the pre-existing `startup_stm32f0xx.ao` and `system_stm32f0xx.ao`.

Usually I find it nicer to list the source files, but YMMV:

```
sources := main.c tools.c devices.c
objects := $(patsubst $.c,%.ao,${sources})
```

(P.S. Using a Static Pattern Rule doesn't really give you any advantage over a normal rule in this noddy case. I just wanted to show a small tweak that would make your makefiles much more consistent in their behaviour.)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I had not been aware of static pattern rules.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's bad form to use an answer to respond to another answer, but I ran out of space in a comment to @bobbogo's answer.

Sorry but I can't agree with your assessment of pattern rules.  It's not true that you will get "strange decisions" based on "whatever is lying around on your harddisks", and it's certainly not arbitrary.

There is one advantage of static pattern rules over pattern rules, and that is also its downside: a static pattern rule is a shorthand for creating an explicit rule, so that rule will always be used to build that target.  A pattern rule, on the other hand, is just one possible way to build a target: if the prerequisites of a pattern rule don't exist and can't be made, then make keeps going and looks for other pattern rules that might be able to build that target.

So if you have multiple possible ways you can build a target then an explicit rule cannot be used for that.

The problem with pattern rules is that if NO pattern rule applies then make just assumes there is no rule to build that target.  If the target exists then make simply says "up to date" (as we see in the question) since there's no rule to build it.  That can be confusing to users.

If you use an explicit rule (including a static pattern rule) and some prerequisite doesn't exist and can't be created, then make will exit with an error, which can make it easier to figure out what went wrong.